# Sortable list + Finding dropped index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, rubaxa-sortable

OK, I'm experimenting a bit with [RubaXa's Sortable plugin](https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable). (Here's a great [example page](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/))

```
    var sort = new Sortable($('#items')[0], {
        animation: 150,

        onUpdate: function(evt/**Event*/){
            var item = evt.item;
            console.log(evt);
        }
    });
```

The Plugin works fine. The thing is how can I get the index at which the element has been dropped? (e.g. from index 2 of the list to index 0)

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/j7fesLkp/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The event that's passed to `onSort` has the fields you need: `oldIndex` and `newIndex`:

```js
var sort = new Sortable(items, {
    onSort: function (evt) {
        console.log(evt.oldIndex + ' -> ' + evt.newIndex);
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- Sortable -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RubaXa/Sortable/dev/Sortable.js"></script>

<ul id="items">
    <li data-id="1">item 1</li>
    <li data-id="2">item 2</li>
    <li data-id="3">item 3</li>
    <li data-id="4">item 4</li>
    <li data-id="5">item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Whoa! Thanks a lot. A correct answer is great, but getting the answer directly from the... source is even better! :-)

Comment: Hmm... I think I have another one for you... Could you please have a look? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881621/weird-issue-with-sortable)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon, `Sortable` can not work with nested blocks. http://jsfiddle.net/j7fesLkp/10/ — why not?

Comment: I think I know what you mean and I did get it to work with this little trick. But I believe @Neograph734 just gave a great answer to this problem. Please, have a look at his comment on the other question. (P.S. Great work with the plugin! It's been the only one that I got to work so smoothly! Keep going! :-) )