# Restrict container/parent for Sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rubaxa-sortable

OK, so here I am again, playing with @RubaXa's [Sortable](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) plugin (and hopefully he is somewhere around here, as this one is simply rather complicated...)

A few discoveries (it took me some time to fully understand the mechanism, but I think I'm quite right)

---

### Case 1

if we set one `div` with same-type contents, it's instantly sortable. E.g.:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myContainer">
     <h3>Item 1</h3>
     <h3>Item 2</h3>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
new Sortable(document.getElementById("myContainer"));
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/b02wfe4o/

---

### Case 2

if we set one `div` with different-type contents (e.g. `h2`s and `h3`s, we also have to specify the `draggable` class. E.g.:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myContainer">
     <h3 class="myDraggable">Item 1</h3>
     <h4 class="myDraggable">Item 2</h4>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
new Sortable(document.getElementById("myContainer"), {
     draggable: '.myDraggable'
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qemz00eq/1/

---

### Case 3

if we set 2 (or more) `div`s, side-by-side, it works pretty much the same way. E.g.:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myContainer1">
     <h3 class="myDraggable">Item 1.1</h3>
     <h4 class="myDraggable">Item 1.2</h4>
</div>

<div id="myContainer2">
     <h3 class="myDraggable">Item 2.1</h3>
     <h4 class="myDraggable">Item 2.2</h4>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
new Sortable(document.getElementById("myContainer1"), {
     draggable: '.myDraggable'
});

new Sortable(document.getElementById("myContainer2"), {
     draggable: '.myDraggable'
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qeyxxj4y/

---

### THE ISSUE

Now, what if sortable A is a child of sortable B?

**HTML**

```
<div id="myContainer1">
     <h3 class="myDraggable">Item 1.1</h3>
     <h4 class="myDraggable">Item 1.2</h4>

     <div id="myContainer2">
           <h3 class="myDraggable">Item 2.1</h3>
           <h4 class="myDraggable">Item 2.2</h4>
     </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
new Sortable(document.getElementById("myContainer1"), {
     draggable: '.myDraggable'
});

new Sortable(document.getElementById("myContainer2"), {
     draggable: '.myDraggable'
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/j7fesLkp/8/

---

Well, now this does not work as expected:

- `myContainer2` items can be moved/sorted perfectly within their container. Which is fine.
- `myContainer1` items though can be moved in `myContainer2` as well, I mean take element **1.1** and put it inside `myContainer2` works - which wasn't happening when the two containers were side-by-side.

So, how can we disable that behaviour? I mean: each container's items must move ONLY within that container and not within its children.

How can that be done?

Comment: Change the class of the second draggable in html and Js. That should work.

Comment: @Neograph734 Awesome answer. And so simple and straightforward. Thanks a lot! Please post it as an answer and I'll gladly accept it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will gave to separate the sortables, and divide them in two different groups. So change the class of one of the groups in html and Js to initialize them as another group.